# Why does the insecure version of my website still exist on Google when I've purchased an SSL certificate?

Tags: security, ssl, heroku

I've recently used Heroku to purchase an ssl certificate for my website (using free dynos). I'm relatively new to web programming and this is my first time trying to get a website secure. I've run into multiple problems but my main one is that when I type into Google the name of my business (jsm websites.com), I click on the link to my website but it sends me to the insecure version of my website (just http, not https).
I'm really confused as to why this is happening, as the ssl certificate has been issued without problems and also I can access the secure version of my website when I manually type into the url bar "https://www.jsm-websites.com". Also, some of the links on google that link to additional pages on my website (such as to the about page or the discover features page) send me to the secure version of my website.
Is there a way to just delete the insecure version of my website so that google will just send people to the secure version? Or do I need to do some fancy coding to direct people there manually?
Thanks for your help, if I've not explained myself well please send me a question.
P.S. I am using goormide as my development environment and the url I am using is [www.jsm-websites.com](http://www.jsm-websites.com).

Comment: Sounds like you should take a look at your DNS provider, the place where you bought your domain. Here you should be able to force any visitors to the secure endpoint. It is also possible to get Heruko to manage your DNS if you look at the settings tab for your dyno.

Comment: Thanks for this, yes I had a look at the domain and played around with a few things. Thanks so much for your help and time :) I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just put below code in your htaccess , Your domain is secured but google will read and takes time to crawl , till you don't put manually you need to put below code in

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domainaname.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! My website is working great now, thank you very much :)

Comment: your welcome if you face any problem further you can let me know